# jQuery Draggable div not reverting to its original position after dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drag and drop example that reverts a draggable object back to it's original position when it is dropped in a droppable div.

once you dropped an object in a droppable div, object sets its position in a droppable div but my problem is when you drag an object out of droppable div it won't back to initial position in a draggable div.

I have tried this which does not work.

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $(".draggable").draggable({
                revert: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0
                    };

                    return !event;
                }
            });

            $(".droppable").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).append(ui.draggable);
                    $(ui.draggable).css({ "left": "0", "top": "0" });

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Syed, You don't want your draggable object to be dropped inside a droppable div !?? So where do you want to drop your draggable object then?

Comment: After dropped, my draggable object sets it position in a droppable div but I want my draggable object to revert its original position

Comment: So ultimately, you can drag it anywhere but cannot drop. wherever you drop it should go back to the initial position..?

Comment: I want to drop an object in a droppable div but My question is that after dropped in a droppable div, I drag an object out of droppable div then object should go back to the initial position

Comment: Not mocking you, but if you drop it in a non-droppable div, then that will stay there?

Comment: No, it will back in droppable div where I dropped

Comment: so, once dropped inside the droppable div, you cannot move it outside? Please update your question with all the information you gave in comments.

Comment: once dropped inside the droppable div, object move outside when dragging but get back in a droppable div where i dropped

Comment: See how this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3ofyzhu/) helps you. If it doesn't fit your needs, let me know/

Comment: Here is my problem, In this fiddle once you dropped an object in a droppable div, object sets its position in a droppable div but my problem is when you drag an object out of droppable div it won't back to initial position.